# Cannot connect from network to ubuntu lamp magento install

Tags: apache, magento, ubuntu-14.04

Hi Apologies if this has been posted below but I cannot seem to find a solution.

I have installed lamp server with ubuntu 14.04 and cannot connect to my magento install from my local network.

I also have joomla installed and it works fine when accessed from the network so I don’t think it is an issue with ports or firewalls. As far as i know i did not select ssh at the magento install.

I need this to work so that I can see how my website displays on mobile devices.

The following setting are set in my /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default.conf:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html


    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

It must be magento specific - as it works in joomla. Not sure if this is relevant but I do not have a .htaccess file in my magento directory.

also it works fine when accessed from the machine where the apache2 server is insatlled for joomla and magento. I have added port forwarding for ports 80, 443 and 8888 on my router to the machine with lamp server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing entry from localhost to your ip address in magento admin system》configuration 》Web for secure and unsecure url.  Your configuration for apache is okay you just have the url rewritten when you access your site.